# NSRegularExpression does not seem to recognize the symbols " and } in expression

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I have a regular expression that works with [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), but does not work with NSRegularExpression in Objective-C. The issue is with the " and } symbols, which is a part of the string I want to search through. 
My regular expression:

```
(?<=\"Here\":\")(.*?)(?=\"})
```

With this expression, Xcode says "expected :", and with \ in front of }, and Xcode also says it doesn't recognize }. I get all these variations to work with RegExr.

For strings like this:

```
{"Something":"Something else", "Here" : "What I want is between these quotation marks"}
```

I looked up in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html), but I didn't find anything about these symbols there.

My code is:

```
NSRegularExpression *regEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\"Here\":\")(.*?)(?=\"})"options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regEx matchesInString:stringToSearch options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringToSearch length])];
[matches count] // Returns 0
```

So where's my mistake? Maybe all the expressions are wrong, and RegExr is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse a string representation of a hash table or dictionary. Are you sure there is not a library better suited for that?

Comment: Yes, that looks like JSON, so NSJSONSerialization could be used.

Comment: Yes, it is JSON. Thanks to both of you, I'm gonna check out that option too, as it is probably more effective. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should looks something like this:

```
@"(?<=\"Here\":\")(.*?)(?=\"\\})"
```

As the `"` are used as delimiters for the `NSString`, you must escape them (ie. add a `\` before all `"` in the string).

**EDIT**: As MartinR noted in the comments, you also need to escape the `}` with two slashes `\\`, as it is a special character in regexes.

This should appear quite clearly with the syntax coloration:

[image: code syntax colored]

Complete code:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=\"Here\":\")(.*?)(?=\"})"
                                                                   options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive // or whatever options you want to use
                                                                     error:&error];
```

Comment: I escaped them in Objective-C and in RegExr, but sadly it only worked in the latter. Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated the question with the "escaping" expression.

Comment: The `}` character has to be escaped in a regular expression (and double-escaped in NSString: `@"...\\}..."`).

Comment: Ah, there you go! \\} at the end there. Thanks to both of you!

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis: Perhaps you can fix it also in the "Complete code" example.

Answer (score 3):

You should just use `NSJSONSerialization` to parse your JSON:

For example

```
NSData *data = ...  // load your {"Something":"Something else", "Here" : "What I want is between these quotation marks"}

NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
if (error)
    NSLog(@"%s: JSONObjectWithData error: %@", __FUNCTION__, error);

NSLog(@"value for Something: %@", dictionary[@"Something"]);
NSLog(@"value for Here: %@", dictionary[@"Here"]);
```

Using regular expressions to parse JSON is going to be inherently fragile. For example, you're clearly assuming that there are no spaces around the colon in the JSON. But there may be (and in fact, in your example, there are). Likewise, it's probably not prudent to assume that the value for "Here" is the last item (and thus that you can look for quotation mark followed by closing brace, whereas at some future date it might be followed by a comma, not a closing brace). Worse, theoretically it's possible (albeit highly unlikely) that the string value, itself, would have a quotation mark and closing brace in it, so you really should check for unescaped quotation marks.

While you could remedy the regular expression, using a JSON parser avoids all of this additional logic that you'd have to build into a complicated regular expression.